# Repeat x-axis values using myplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have below data and I want to plot the graph with repeating x-axis.

```
| 30 |  | 0.650297475 |
| 40 |  | 0.657665519 |
| 50 |  | 0.669169975 |
| 60 |  | 0.695916956 |
| 50 |  | 0.680254894 |
| 40 |  | 0.663912144 |
| 30 |  | 0.653692469 |
| 20 |  | 0.644423894 |
| 10 |  | 0.637784575 |
|  0 |  | 0.626213656 |
| 10 |  | 0.637769063 |
| 20 |  | 0.643006988 |
| 30 |  | 0.646742206 |
| 50 |  | 0.668539731 |
| 60 |  | 0.694959931 |
| 50 |  | 0.679511669 |
| 40 |  | 0.6633013   |
| 30 |  | 0.653026313 |
| 20 |  | 0.644970369 |
| 10 |  | 0.63772925  |
|  0 |  | 0.626494163 |
| 20 |  | 0.643006456 |
| 30 |  | 0.646692806 |
| 40 |  | 0.656562469 |
| 50 |  | 0.668683988 |
| 60 |  | 0.695289806 |
| 50 |  | 0.680420325 |
| 40 |  | 0.663145675 |
| 30 |  | 0.654077156 |
```

I am trying to plot it using myplotlib

```
x=range(len(x_axis))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
ax.set_xticks(x_axis, minor=True)
CH1 = ax.plot(x, y_axis)
ax.legend([parameter])#,bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1),loc=2, borderaxespad=0
fig.savefig("plotfile_get_Vendor_version_here"+".png")
plt.close(fig)
```

But the x-axis values are terminating at 30.
I understand this is because of range function. Is there anyway I can fix this.
I would be really helpful for the support.

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do.  What do you mean 'repeated x-axis'?

Answer (score 2):

You need `ax.set_xticks()` to set the tick positions and `ax.set_xticklabels()` to actually print the ticks. Try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# the data:
x_axis = np.array(
    [ 30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  50.,  40.,  30.,  20.,  10.,   0.,  10.,
      20.,  30.,  50.,  60.,  50.,  40.,  30.,  20.,  10.,   0.,  20.,
      30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  50.,  40.,  30.])
y_axis = np.array(
    [ 0.65029748,  0.65766552,  0.66916997,  0.69591696,  0.68025489,
     0.66391214,  0.65369247,  0.64442389,  0.63778457,  0.62621366,
     0.63776906,  0.64300699,  0.64674221,  0.66853973,  0.69495993,
     0.67951167,  0.6633013 ,  0.65302631,  0.64497037,  0.63772925,
     0.62649416,  0.64300646,  0.64669281,  0.65656247,  0.66868399,
     0.69528981,  0.68042033,  0.66314567,  0.65407716])

x=range(len(x_axis))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xticks(x) # set tick positions
# Labels are formated as integers:
ax.set_xticklabels(["{:d}".format(int(v)) for v in x_axis]) 
ax.plot(x, y_axis)  

fig.canvas.draw() # actually draw figure
plt.show() # enter GUI loop (for non-interactive interpreters)
```

Alternatively you could try something like [this](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/many_facets.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. the trick was in using ax.set_xticklabels. I am successfully able to resolve the issue.

Comment: I wanted x axis to display continuous values i.e., 30,40,50,60,10,20,30,40....without using xtricks the python will clutter the the axis so I was only getting 10,20,30,40,50,60.